# core data tableView crash

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, crash, unrecognized-selector

As the name states I am working with `UITableView` and CoreData. I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which has title and detail label. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it crashes. I have found the issue I was passing NULL but the  **issue** is it doesn't crash at

```
cell.detailLabel.text = [[factors valueForKey:@"factorsdescription"] lastObject];
```

but after many times `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called and even on that cell in which I'm not passing null. any ideas?

crash Log

> [NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x34ed3690
>   2015-08-20 18:58:37.364 MASTER[1535:89769] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: show your crash log.

Comment: @PradumnaPatil added crash log

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code and point out the exact line causing the crash. But clearly this means that `[[factors valueForKey:@"factorsdescription"] lastObject]` is returning an `NSNull` value and not an `NSString`. You have to check for this.

Comment: @rmaddy yes I'm now checking whether it's null or not. But my question is why it doesn't crash when it found null but later when it has string value

Comment: `nil` and an instance of the `NSNull` class are two very completely different things.

Comment: @rmaddy yes I'm checking for [NSNull null] but that isn't my question. The question is why it didn't crash when null was returned but later when I can successfully log next item.. I mean isn't it supposed to crash at that cell where it got NSNull and not go further and call cellForRowAtIndexPath again.. I'm sorry if I'm not being clear

Comment: Update your question with relevant code and the stack trace of the crash. Point out the exact line causing the crash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87545/discussion-between-misha-and-rmaddy).